# Selective Explicit Loading in WCF Data Service

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm about to implement a web service for my database, perhaps using WCF Data Services.  Some of the objects I need to make available have child objects that need to be present for the objects to be useful.  But because of lazy loading in the Entity Framework, those child objects are not going to be automatically loaded.

I'm going to be calling this service using JSON, and I don't want to have to specify the [$expand option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358709.aspx) in each call.  And it's not clear to me where I would use the LoadProperty method (same link), since I'm just writing the `InitializeService` method and letting the framework do the rest.

Is there a way to configure it to explicitly load some child objects and not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF Data Services currently doesn't support auto-expand on the server. The client always has to ask for expansions.

You could implement some kind of a workaround around the WCF DS, by modifying the incoming request. So for example if the client sends request for ~/Products you could modify it before it gets to WCF DS and let it process ~/Products&$expand=Category and that way effectively achieve auto-expand. But for such a service to be robust, you would have to parse the query URL and only add the expand if there's not already one in there and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is if its always necessary for the child object to be present, can we make the child object complex types instead of entities, so that they always come along with the parent. Is there a strong reason for the child objects to be individual entities?

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by complex types vs entities?